# SSL Enabled Host

Tags: java, ssl, client, host

Problem - 
I would like to connect to  SSL enabled Server Host(has signed certificates from verisign). This host approves/declines the payment transactions.

Assumption - 1. ClientAuth is not required. 2. I am not dealing with  HTTPS

I would like to write a java client that will connect with this host and will send request and  receive response. Please correct if my understanding is not correct.

1. Java client need to use package - 'javax.net.ssl.*' . This package
   has 'SSLSocket' class to make a connection with SSL Host.
2. For Java client 'keystore'/client certificates (signed by verisign)
   is not required. It would only required when clientAuth is enabled
   (TRUE).
3. Do i need to have a provision in my client code to first verify
   Server certificate and then transfer the data ? is this step
   mandatory?
4. Am i bypassing some mandatory steps?

Thanks,
Raj Hebbar

Answer (score 1):

To create a secure socket (client side) you can use:

```
//An SSL socket can't be created from scratch. We need a Factory that
//handles the underlying logic that allows create a SSL socket
SocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();

//Get the socket from the Factory
SSLSocket  socket = (SSLSocket) socketFactory.createSocket(host, port);
```

Now, at runtime when you create the java client/socket the factory will perform the famous "SSL handshake" and some verification will be performed. By default a java client/socket will:

- **Check if the certificate of the server correspond to the 'host'**: Each certificate has a 'server name' and this certificate should be downloaded only from that server. So, if you get a 'www.google.com' certificate from a 'www.oracle.com' server this verification will fail.
- **Check if the certificate is a trusted one**: if it is not signed by an authority, or the authority chain cannot be checked, or if it is
  not included in your 'trusted certificate repository' this validation
  will fail.

***IMPORTANT: The first bullet point that explains the host name check is wrong: this does not happens for SSLSocket but for HTTPS clients. Thanks to @EJP and @Gergely Szilagyi for pointing this out***

**NOTE:** There is a way to solve issues with these validations like:

- To Bypass/Turn off the server check, please read this [post](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/how-to-bypass-certificate-checking-in-a-java-web-service-client/) (not recommended!)
- To add a certificate to the client trusted repository check this [post](http://java.ggarciao.com/2009/12/how-to-create-secure-socket-ssl-in-java.html)

Comment: First bullet point is incorrect. Hostname checking is part of HTTPS, not SSL. In Java terms it is done by HttpURLConnection, not SSLSocket.

Comment: @EJP: to be precise, it's in `sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.checkURLSpoofing`

Comment: @EJP I strongly agree with you. My bad

Answer (score 0):

1. Correct.
2. Correct.
3. No, it happens automatically. You can add a handshake listener that checks the certificate, or get the peer certificate from the SSLSession, but it is possible to proceed without it.
4. Yes.